# When does the limit of the ratio of consecutive terms of a sequence exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to understand and obtain some sufficient conditions under which the limit of the ratio of consecutive terms of a sequence exists.

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of positive integers, such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n =\infty$.

When does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exist?

If we assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\root n \of {x_n}=a$, then I can show that the required limit, if it exists, is equal to $a$. I don't want to ask the question in extreme generality, so I am assuming that the sequence $x_n$ grows at most exponentially.

For instance, since $y_n:=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is bounded (when the growth is at most exponential), one such condition is monotonicity of the sequence $y_n$, which gives me the condition $x_{n+1}x_{n-1}\geq x_n^2$.

One of my questions is whether the limit in question exists for exponentially growing sequences. Also, what sufficient conditions are there for sub-exponential sequences?

Any help appreciated!